# What happens when we try to erase non existent key from hash_set

Tags: c++, std

What happens when we try to erase non existent key from `hash_set` class from [SGI's STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_set.html)?
Does the call to `hash_set::erase` first try to find the key and then delete it?

Comment: Depends on the data structure, really. Which `hash_set` are you talking about? There's no class of that name in the standard library.

Comment: What's `hash_set`? There's no such thing in the standard library.

Comment: Are you talking about this implementation of C++ hash set : http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_set.html ?

Comment: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_set.html

Comment: This class is an SGI extension; it is not part of the C++ standard.

Comment: Note that Microsoft has a similar extension of a `hash_set`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/1t4xas78.aspx
Their recommendation is to use `unordered_set` instead, which is part of C++ standard since C++11:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code used by your implementation of `hash_set`, it's the erase method of `hashtable` :

```
template <class _Val, class _Key, class _HF, class _Ex, class _Eq, class _All>
typename hashtable<_Val,_Key,_HF,_Ex,_Eq,_All>::size_type 
hashtable<_Val,_Key,_HF,_Ex,_Eq,_All>::erase(const key_type& __key)
{
  const size_type __n = _M_bkt_num_key(__key);
  _Node* __first = _M_buckets[__n];
  size_type __erased = 0;

  if (__first) {
    _Node* __cur = __first;
    _Node* __next = __cur->_M_next;
    while (__next) {
      if (_M_equals(_M_get_key(__next->_M_val), __key)) {
        __cur->_M_next = __next->_M_next;
        _M_delete_node(__next);
        __next = __cur->_M_next;
        ++__erased;
        --_M_num_elements;
      }
      else {
        __cur = __next;
        __next = __cur->_M_next;
      }
    }
    if (_M_equals(_M_get_key(__first->_M_val), __key)) {
      _M_buckets[__n] = __first->_M_next;
      _M_delete_node(__first);
      ++__erased;
      --_M_num_elements;
    }
  }
  return __erased;
}
```

As you can see, it tries to find the key before deleting the node, and **does nothing if the key doesn't exist**.

Also, from the [*SGI* documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/HashedAssociativeContainer.html) :

> Erase key : Destroys all elements whose key is the same as k, and
>   removes them from a. The return value is the number of elements
>   that were erased, i.e. the old value of a.count(k).

Comment: And, does "nothing" if the key isn't found, more importantly.

Comment: So I need not check contains() before erasing key?

Comment: @user1393608 since this behavior is specified in the documentation, that would seem redundant.

Comment: I have 2 hash_sets, I want to erase all elements from hash_set1 that are also in hash_set2, so simply iterating over the hash_set2 and erasing it from hash_set1 would work?

Comment: @user1393608 Aha! The real question (c:

Comment: @PeterWood: The real question is why he isn't using standard c++ facilities.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Maybe he doesn't have access to the C++11 `unordered_set` and doesn't want the binary search trees provided by the standard C++ `set` or `map`.